# How to get TaxKeyword for items in Drive - Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, taxonomy, microsoft-graph-sdks

i want to search all the items in a drive based on their TaxKeyword.

To begin, i tried to get informations for a list item and it is working.
But for an item in a drive, there is no TaxKeyword in response content.

I tried this query :

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/d506b5d3-fa85-4510-88fb-16049640ce8f/drive/items('01OKQZOOXUZW65LYSZNZBZXB3QKR6LKWIP')

But there is no value related to TaxKeyword.

Thanks for helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that want to get all informations including TaxKeywords from a drive item.
We can play with a drive as if it was a list.
So i used the following query to get informations incuding TaxKeywords of all drive item :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteId/lists/ListId/items?expand=fields
```

Hope it can help someone.